# Segmentation fault error (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error in below code.

Please suggest where I am going wrong?

```
#include "string.h"
int main(){
char *str=NULL;
strcpy(str,"something");
printf("%s",str);
return 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/Wo9dIcnK

I was going through a site where I saw this problem and tried to compile the code. It says expected output should be (null). Here is the link [cquestions.com/2010/10/c-interview-questions-and-answers.html](http://cquestions.com/2010/10/c-interview-questions-and-answers.html) 13th question last example

Comment: You need to let the first argument of `strcpy` point to allocated memory that you may write to. Passing `NULL` as the first argument tends to lead to an access violation.

Comment: The only value you ever assign to `str` is `NULL`. Then you try to copy a string to NULL and then print a string from NULL. How's that supposed to work?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit why would you think that? **[Hanlon's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor)**

Comment: @sehe: Because it's very basic, is covered at almost the start of a proper C book, and has been asked here many, many times. Then look at the rep outcome below.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It appears the asker was confused by a bad site. See the comments on haccks' answer below.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Huh. The OP doesn't control the votes, right. Also, I didn't question whether the question made no sense. I asked you, where you found the allegation of sock-puppetry

Comment: @sehe: First of all, I never alleged sock-puppetry. Secondly, they do control if they pay someone else to vote, which was the whole point. Lastly, I was _joking_ in order to vent off steam about this sort of post. y so srs! =)

Comment: @FredLarson - Right. site content is misleading. Thanks.

Comment: @User42: The given answers on that site are partly flat-out wrong, misleading or at least bad. Anyway, interview questions shall show the asker that you can solve problems, not that you ate a standard or can regurgitate answers to standard questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `str` before copying string to it.

```
char *str = malloc(10) // Length of string "Something" + 1
```

Note that after assigning `NULL` to `str`, it points nowhere as [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/null/null1.html) says:

> [...] a null pointer points definitively nowhere; it is not the address of any object or function.

*If `str` is not the address of any object then how could it be possible to copy anything to it?*

Comment: char *str= malloc(10);
str=NULL;
strcpy(str,"something");

Still giving error.

char *str= malloc(10);
//str=NULL;
strcpy(str,"something");

No error. Why?

Comment: Why you are assigning `NULL` after allocating space? Do you know the use of `NULL`?

Comment: Not exactly. I am reading about Null only. I was going through a site where I saw this problem and tried to compile the code. It says expected output should be (null). Here is the link http://www.cquestions.com/2010/10/c-interview-questions-and-answers.html
13th question last example.

Comment: @User42; I just visited that site. I advice you to keep away from that site. It is not up to date. Many answers are based on the code compilation on Turbo C++ which is obsolete now.

Comment: @Deduplicator; Oops! Good catch :)

Comment: Yeah. I also notices the same. Many output and examples are based on Turbo C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int size = 10;
    char *str=NULL;
    str=malloc(size);
    strcpy(str,"something");
    printf("%s", str);

}
```

Its always important to indent your code also :$

Answer (score -1):

You can use malloc or strdup in you case.